Modification of Random Forest Classifier
i am trying to change the functionality of a random forest classifier. While usually features are selected at random for each split, i want one specific feature to be evaluated at each split. I know this can impact performance but i want to try out whether this is a good idea in a very specific use case. So the result of the adaptation shall be: features used for splitting are selected at random (as usual) but one specific feature (say index 15) is always considered (not necessarily used). To the best of my knowledge, there is no function that allows me to specify that (if there is please let me know).

It's really unclear what Fortran is doing here??

Well i am unsure whether the problem actually lies in the fortran parts of the code.

You can consider the {ranger} package, which offers this option. And is magnitudes faster.

I can't see any "Fortran part of the code", actually...

I suggest you edit the question down to roughly the first paragraph where you ask if such functionality already exists, then we reopen so that @MichaelM can upgrade his comment to an answer. The parameter always.split.variables is new to me, thanks!

thanks @MichaelM i wasn´t aware of always.split.variables either!
